# Unable to edit an web element which is under expand grid using selenium web driver.

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mousemove

am tring to edit text for an element which is under expand grid.

(Open URL www.treegrid.com/treegrid/www/  -> Edit element under Order2 i.e. MS Windows XP Pro OEM)

1. I  have tired using jsClick.
2. Focus on the element first then perform click using actions (action.moveToElement)
3. tired with Mousemove & perform clcik
4. Tried click element by getting its coordinates.

but still no luck. 
looking forword for your help!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through your query. To interact with it you need to click on it first then sendKeys. To try this out you can do it as:

```
driver.get("http://www.treegrid.com/treegrid/www/");
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//tr[contains(.,'<your order no.>')]/following-sibling::tr//td[contains(.,'<text of td>')][contains(@class,'GMText')]"))
    .click();
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//tr[contains(.,'<your order no.>')]/following-sibling::tr//td[contains(.,'<text of td>')][contains(@class,'GMText')]"))
    .sendKeys("<text to send>");
```